# Яка різниця між стовпом і щоглою?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Також спадають на думку ще два слова, котрі є плюс-мінус синонімами до вищезгаданих двох: вежа і вишка. Різницю між вежою і стовпом я інтуітивно розумію, але слово "щогла" я почув уперше сьогодні, тому ще не зовсім розумію його значення. Гугл каже, що щогла часто буває на кораблях, але не обов'язково. То мене цікавить не корабельна щогла, а, так би мовити, сухопутна.

Comment: Щогла у тлумачному словнику: http://sum.in.ua/s/shhoghla

Comment: Як на мене стовп значно нижче щогли ), щогла, більш інженерно складна конструкція.
P.S.Щогла на суднах і кораблях. Корабель - це військове судно.

Comment: Щогла зв'язку: http://zaporizhia.all.biz/uk/shchogla-dlya-anten-zvyazku-g421505#.WTVqeGiGO71 На стовп не схожа, на вишку теж.

Answer (score 12):

Усе просто - стовп (слуп) стоїть сам по собі, а щогла підтримувана тросами із різних боків.

Зі [збірнику наукових праць](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0hc-my6fUAhUhDZoKHbRjBTIQFgiBATAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Firbis-nbuv.gov.ua%2Fcgi-bin%2Firbis_nbuv%2Fcgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF%2FZNPISK_2012_9_12.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEd0TMjzaBAN-AwIcbxnNL2Vatxnw&sig2=Boyihm2ddLw4PbBjKY0S6w) Українського інституту сталевих конструкцій імені В.М. Шимановського. – Випуск 9, 2012 р. Молчанов Д.С. *Дефекти опор мобільного зв'язку*:

> Щогли – це конструкції, які складаються із стовбура, постійного за
>   висотою перерізу, та системи відтяжок. Стовбур щогли зазвичай є три-,
>   чотиригранним, із поясами та решіткою, виконаними з прокатних кутиків,
>   труб або суцільних стрижнів. Також існують щогли круглого перерізу,
>   стовбур яких виконано з труби. Стійкість щогл забезпечена
>   встановленими відтяжками, що виконані зі сталевих тросів. Кількість
>   рівнів відтяжок визначається конструктивними особливостями щогли.
>   Найчастіше наземні щогли мають висоту 40...80 м. Щогли є достатньо
>   економічними конструкціями, проте вони потребують постійного
>   технічного нагляду, що полягає в контролі монтажного натягу відтяжок та
>   вертикальності стовбура щогли.